# Removing empty space on first button of pure css navigation menu bar

Tags: html, css, navigation, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to build a very simple pure css navigation bar, but have hit a roadbump.
I'm using a html list, and the first item seems to have extra space to it's left which I cannot get rid of.

[Live Example](http://f.cl.ly/items/3t072L442N220U0H1R2h/index.html)

[Also on JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zLAhj/) [UPDATE: Strangely JSFIDDLE doesn't display this problem, renders the nav bar as I want it to look, must be their back end that fixes whatever's wrong.]

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 62.5%;
    color: #666;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
}
header {
    min-width: 400px;
    max-width: 700px;
    padding: 40px 8px 0;
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
}
header nav ul {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
header nav li {
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
    position: relative;
}
header nav li:first-child {
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
}
header nav li:last-child {
    border: none;
}
header nav li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
    padding: 7px 15px;
}
header nav li a:hover {
    color: #000;
    background: #f6f6f6;
}
```

HTML:

```
<header>
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Welcome</a></li>
    <li><a href="events.html">Events</a></li>
    <li><a href="join.html">Join A Team</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="faq.php">Facebook</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</header>
```

Would really appreciate if someone could help me out.

Comment: Check it on other browsers as well, on Opera, items are not appearing at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove padding from the `<ul>`.

```
header nav ul {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: seems to fix it! Can't believe I missed it. Also is there a easy way to retain the border radius when a:hover is triggered?

Comment: I would suggest assigning the border-radius to the `<a>`'s instead of the `<ul>`. You can use `header nav ul li a:first-child` for the left-most item on the menu, and assign a `last` class to the right-most list item, then do `header nav ul li.last a`.

Answer (score 2):

Write

```
ul{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
```

or use `reset sheet` it's better to use http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded/

Comment: thanks, yep it was just the padding that caused the problem, also is there a easy way to retain the border radius when a:hover is triggered?